# How to use service method in Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine, entity

I'm doing quite a big Symfony2 project (unfortunately on a database which structure I cannot modify) and I'm stuck with this:

I have a User entity which contains (amongst other fields) the username field.

I also have a ProfileField entity that corresponds with extra fields for User (like firstname or lastname, favourite color or whatever you would like to ask a user about).

Finally there is the ConfigService, which basically get's a certain value for certain key from the database.
In this particular case it's all about a little config value called 'username_format'. It can take one of 3 values: 'username', 'firstname' or 'firstnamelastname'.

Depending on that value I need to display the properly formatted username. If the value is 'username' - I'm just returning username field value from User entity.
For both 2nd and 3rd case, so when I need to get a custom ProfileField corresponding to that particular user, I've created a simple service (called usernameFormatService) that has ConfigService injected and a method called getNameFromId($userId). The method checks the config value and pulls the correct values for correct user. This all works very nice, but...

I have a blog overview page, in which the formatted username is shown amongst other fields (like title, creation date etc). The Blog entity has manyToOne relationship with User entity. From the mapping I'm getting the username of course, and if 'username_format' config value says that I need firstname for example, I'm pulling it with usernameFormatService inside Twig template and everything is working like it should.

The real problem starts when I need to be able to sort by each column, that means formatted username column also. I'm using Doctrine QueryBuilder to fetch db results, and basically I need the formatted username value somewhere inside User entity (I think) to be able to sort the blogs by this value BEFORE they are pulled from database (why before? pagination).

Can anyone give me at least a hint where to look or how to do it?

**Update:**

To make it more clear maybe:

Right now the user name that is displayed in overview table is being resolved by usernameFormatService, which uses ConfigService to get 'platform_username_format' config value form the database and, depending on that config value, returns formatted user name.
If it comes to sorting, I need to somehow get that formatted username BEFORE I will actually query the database, so I can get sorted results.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if I understood everything correctly here, I would do something as written below.

Now, what am not sure of is if each user has an option to choose how to view data. Therefore, I hardcoded `username_format` in service definition but that behavior could be easily altered.

### 1. ConfigService

I would change your `getNameFromId` to `getNameForUser`:

```
class ConfigService{
    private $usernameFormat;
    private $repository;

    public function __construct($repository, $usernameFormat){
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->usernameFormat = $usernameFormat;
    }

    public function getNameForUser(User $user){
        switch ($this->usernameFormat){
            case "username":
                return $user->getUsername();
            case "firstname":
                return $user->getFirstName();
            case "firstnamelastname":
                reteurn $user->getFirstName() . ' ' . $user->getLastname();
        }
    }

    public function getAllUsers($page){ 
        return $this->repository->getUsers($page, $this->usernameFormat);
    }
}
```

### 2. ConfigService definition

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="my.repository.class">Your\Namespace\FooRepository</parameter>
    <parameter key="config.service.class">Your\Namespace\Service\ConfigService</parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="user.repository"
             class="%my.repository.class%"
             factory-service="doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
             factory-method="getRepository">
            <argument>YourBundle:User</argument>
    </service>

    <service id="config.service" class="%config.service.class%">
        <argument type="service" id="my.repository.class" />
        <argument type="string">username</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

### 3. Repository

```
public UserRepository extends EntityRepository{
    public function getUsers($page, $usernameFormat){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

        /**
         * Rest of quering rules go here: WHERE predicate, ORDERing, pagination
         */

         return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();   
    }
}
```

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: You've misunderstood me. To make it more clear read the updated question. If it still isn't clear please let me know :)